# umbrella term for microtiter plate, petri dish, cell culture flask etc

Tags: terminology, microscopy, imaging

I'm looking for a term I can use in a software user interface that includes anything that may carry cell cultures or similar biological imaging samples (ie that may conceivably go into an automated microscope).

Since it's for a user interface, the term should be short and intuitive.  It should not depend on context.

Examples:

- *vessel, carrier, dish* --- often used for what I mean, but not intuitive out of context.
- *cell culture carrier* --- too long, also potentially too specific.

Comment: A flask or petri dish do not go into a microscope. Can you specify what you are exactly after? Are you after **containers** to grow cells? Or are you after **plates** to do repetitive stuff with cells (add substrate, coloring agents etc), or are you after **carriers** that go under a microscope?

Comment: @AliceD: anything you might grow cells in, potentially adding reagents, potentially fixate, and then image, for example [these plates](https://www.thermofisher.com/order/catalog/product/152028#/152028).  And yes, we do image cultures in flasks like [this one](https://shop.gbo.com/en/usa/products/bioscience/cell-culture-products/cellstar-cell-culture-flasks/standard-cell-culture-flasks/660160.html)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I left the field some 20 years ago, so I'll not even bother trying to answer this question, but it may help others to answer your Q. Good luck programming!

Comment: This sort of question is not really about biology. It may be a better fit for English Language & Usage with the tag “technical” (or the like). There are technical people there who delight in this sort of thing (as well as people who know nothing about the subject but can’t stop themselves answering every question in a comment).

Comment: @AliceD No problem. Just a suggestion, anyway.

Comment: @David thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @David I know of EL&U (and I've posted there in the past), and you're right, this is a single-word-request (one of the tags there).  The reason I posted on biology SE is that I thought the chances of the right person seeing the question here are vastly higher.

Comment: Could be. You never know.